# Setting up a dns server on CentOs 5.8

Tags: domain-name-system, centos5

I'm having some problems with setting up my dns server on my vps (CentOs 5.8 32 bit)

I have configured a dns zone with the ISPConfig 3 wizard. 
My name servers are registered at my domain registrar (at Yahoo)

I configured my domain to use my name servers:

```
ns1.mydomain.com
ns2.mydomain.com
```

Still, when I go to my domain, it says page not found.

---

The real error is "can't find domainname.com"

---

named.conf (in /var/named/chroot/etc)

```
//
// Sample named.conf BIND DNS server 'named' configuration file
// for the Red Hat BIND distribution.
//
// See the BIND Administrator's Reference Manual (ARM) for details, in:
//   file:///usr/share/doc/bind-*/arm/Bv9ARM.html
// Also see the BIND Configuration GUI : /usr/bin/system-config-bind and
// its manual.
//
options
{
    // Those options should be used carefully because they disable port
    // randomization
    // query-source    port 53;
    // query-source-v6 port 53;

    // Put files that named is allowed to write in the data/ directory:
    directory "/var/named"; // the default
    dump-file               "data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file         "data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file      "data/named_mem_stats.txt";

};
logging
{
/*      If you want to enable debugging, eg. using the 'rndc trace' command,
 *      named will try to write the 'named.run' file in the $directory (/var/named).
 *      By default, SELinux policy does not allow named to modify the /var/named  directory,
 *      so put the default debug log file in data/ :
 */
     channel default_debug {
         file "data/named.run";
         severity dynamic;
     };
};
//
// All BIND 9 zones are in a "view", which allow different zones to be served
// to different types of client addresses, and for options to be set for groups
// of zones.
//
// By default, if named.conf contains no "view" clauses, all zones are in the
// "default" view, which matches all clients.
//
// If named.conf contains any "view" clause, then all zones MUST be in a view;
// so it is recommended to start off using views to avoid having to restructure
// your configuration files in the future.
//
```

Comment: Page not Found implies the DNS is working OK as your webserver is responding.

Comment: Sorry I meant "can't find domainname.com"

Comment: What is your domain name ?

Comment: my domain name is uk2be.com

Comment: The `named.conf` doesn't show anything about your domain nor any include of other files.  There's definitely something very wrong about your config.  ISPConfig doesn't seem to be able to configure bind properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something wrong with the configuration of the DNS server software on your server.  This can be seen from the following DNS diagnosis questions.

You domain is correctly delegated (`dig ns uk2be.com`):

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;uk2be.com.         IN  NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
uk2be.com.      172800  IN  NS  ns1.uk2be.com.
uk2be.com.      172800  IN  NS  ns2.uk2be.com.
```

The glue records are existing (`dig ns1.uk2be.com` and `dig ns2.uk2be.com`), although it's a single server:

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ns1.uk2be.com.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ns1.uk2be.com.      172726  IN  A   46.37.174.74

------

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ns2.uk2be.com.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ns2.uk2be.com.      172714  IN  A   46.37.174.74
```

But your DNS server is not responding to any query (`dig soa uk2be.com @46.37.174.74` or `dig www.uk2be.com @46.37.174.74`):

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> soa uk2be.com @46.37.174.74
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 24146
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;uk2be.com.         IN  SOA

;; Query time: 21 msec
;; SERVER: 46.37.174.74#53(46.37.174.74)
;; WHEN: Fri Aug 17 18:30:18 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 27

------

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> www.uk2be.com @46.37.174.74
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 21070
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.uk2be.com.         IN  A

;; Query time: 17 msec
;; SERVER: 46.37.174.74#53(46.37.174.74)
;; WHEN: Fri Aug 17 18:30:48 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 31
```

Providing your server is actually using this IP address (46.37.174.74), something is wrongly configured on your DNS software.  Which DNS software are you using?  Can you see anything wrong in the logs?

For testing purposes, you might want to try a few online tools:

- http://pingability.com/zoneinfo.jsp
- http://dns.squish.net/
- http://www.checkdns.net/

Comment: Hey, thx for the reply. I use BIND as DNS software. Just checking these sites you gave me. On pingability it says: uk2be.com does not have an IP Address (A) record. Why does it say that? I have configured an A record for that domain in ISPConfig

Comment: Yes, you've configured that in ISPConfig, but somehow ISPConfig hasn't made the right configuration into BIND.  Your server doesn't reply correctly to any DNS request it receives.  That's why these online tools say they cannot find your domain nor any A record.  You should check the error messages or the logs from ISPConfig, but also the logs of BIND.  This is usually in `/var/log/named.log` or you might even find something in `/var/log/messages`

Comment: There's nothing in the ispconfig logs. But the messages.log says: Aug 17 21:21:28 uk2be named[591]: client 207.xxx.xxx.xxx#58217: bad zone transfer request: 'uk2be.com/IN': non-authoritative zone (NOTAUTH)

Comment: This log message states that bind (named) doesn't know about your domain (non-authoritative, meaning your dns thinks it is not responsible for your domain).  You need to check all the `named` log entries in `messages.log` to spot something useful.  We'd need to have the full `named.conf` to try to spot something there.  There clearly is something wrong in your ISPConfig and bind setup.

Comment: I updated my post with the named.conf

Comment: Seeing your `named.conf` is coming from a chroot, I've seen several post with issues between chrooted bind and IPSConfig.  You might want to try to remove the `bind-chroot` package if you have it installed.

Comment: I decided to start over with a fresh install and followed this tutorial on howtoforge.com (http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-centos-5.7-x86_64-ispconfig-3) of the perfect centos 5.7 server and it's working now .. obviously it was the named.conf file that wasn't configured :)